# Apply a css rule to even numbered table rows - reset after header row

Tags: html, css

How can I "reset" the even/odd count in CSS everytime a specific row is displayed?

It looks like this:

```
header   header   header
even     even     even
odd      odd      odd
Subhead  Subhead  Subhead
even     even     even
```

So no matter where the subhead row is, the next row is always even?

Comment: does that row have a certain class?  Will there be only one of them, or is it unlimited?  Are you open to changing the HTML structure of the table to solve this?

Comment: It's unlimited, I can give it a class, but I probably can't change the structure of the table; it's essentially just a large report.

Comment: I can just do it using a server-side counter, but I had hoped for a nicer css solution.

Comment: at first I was thinking using a separate `<tbody>` for each subhead grouping, but if you can't change that structure, then a server-side counter is probably the best solution here.  unless you want your CSS file to be insanely long.

Comment: Some ideas: `:nth-child()` selector, sibling selector (`~`), and `:not()` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `~` along with `:nth-of-type` selector:

```
tr.subhead ~ tr:nth-of-type(even) {
/* your style*/
}
```

`.subhead ~ tr` will scope all `tr` starting one just next to `subhead`.

Comment: nth-of-type here will still count from the very first tr.

Comment: @andi You're right. But maybe it's not strong condition to "reset counter". I think my solution is enough to make subsections visually different. Especially if subheaders have id-s, which allow to style different subsections with appropriate different styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it for single row following the `tr.subhead` with css `+` selector, like:

```
tr.subhead + tr {
  /* even styles */
}
```

However it won't reset the whole structure, and the `tr.subhead + tr + tr` will get even styles again.